# How to revoke Sign in with Apple credentials for a specific app?

Tags: apple-sign-in

We are testing the new [Sign in with Apple](https://developer.apple.com/sign-in-with-apple/) feature with our application, and on the initial request we are provided with the users full name and email address (if the user enabled these options).

However on subsequent requests, this data is not provided only the `identityToken` and `accessToken` are provided.

This has made testing this service difficult as each time we want to test the sign up of a new user, we need a new user account.

Is there a way to revoke which app(s) are using Sign in with Apple for a certain Apple ID?

Comment: What throws an even bigger wrench into this, is that Apple App Review requires that you not collect the information yourself via an onboarding process (we just got rejected for this from the app store on an update). This creates a chicken-egg problem since I can't guarantee I'll have the name fields even though I request them.

Comment: Here is what we got via the app store resolution center:

We noticed that after users authenticate their account with Sign in with Apple, they are required to take additional steps before they can access content and features in your app. Specifically:

- Your app requires users to provide their name and/or email address after using Sign in with Apple.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210426 best way they explain it

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can do this from the iPhone Settings.
Open the Settings app then tap on your name at the top. Then press "Password & Security", then "Apple ID logins". 
They should all be listed there and can be deleted.

Comment: Looks like that has changed to `Apps Using Apple ID` at least on iOS 14.

Comment: You should be able to do this programmatically , that is why apple gave the revoke tokens endpoint https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/revoke_tokens

Answer (score 21):

We have found a manual way to achieve this which has helped tremendously with testing so I thought it would be good to share here:

1. Go to https://appleid.apple.com and sign in
2. Scroll to down Security > APPS & WEBSITES USING APPLE ID > Manage
3. Click the appropriate app > Stop Using Apple ID

[image: Step 1]

And then after clicking on the right app:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do that by API?

Comment: After this the account results as "Unknown" but it does not let user to create a new account (it does not return a new email and fullname)

Comment: There isnt "Apps & Websites using apple ID" option anymore

Comment: I had an issue that this option was missing on my account. I had to create another account that worked well, though I still don't know what was wrong with my previous account. The email address of user was never returned in the "corrupted" account (regardless of scope) and so Im afraid that similar issue might occur to users

Comment: @MatteoGaggiano I encountered the exact same issue today. After doing "Stop using Apple ID" once, I am not able to sign in with that apple id in our app again as the email and full name is not returned anymore. Did you find a solution in the meantime?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the JWT id token, you should be able to decode it and retrieve the user info (name / email) from that directly.

For example, you can visit a site like https://jwt.ms/ and paste the id token there to see user-related data.

Edit: After doing some testing, it looks like the first/last name of the user is **not** in the decoded JWT token subsequent login requests. But, the **email** field *is* there, even though it is `null` in the apple id credential.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple and 100% working**

If you have iphone which is used by you and using same apple id, now you can also remove app which is using apple sign in for your apple id.

Simply follow **steps**:

-Go to Settings

-Tap on your name

-Tap on Security

-Tap on Apps using apple id

-Select app which you want to remove

-At bottom there is an option "Stop Using Apple ID"

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]