# Apple Sign-In: How to use it for custom server endpoint authentication?

Tags: ios, server, oauth, apple-sign-in

My use case is that once I have a user signed into my app, I use the Oauth token, resulting from the sign-in, when I make endpoint calls from my app to my custom server-- to authenticate the caller. E.g., I use [Google Sign In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios) in this way.

This method (e.g., with Google Sign In) has several useful properties:

1. Updated tokens are created automatically on the client app.
2. My custom server can easily verify the validity of the token, using Google's endpoints.
3. Initial token verification can take place early in the endpoint request processing-- without access to the custom servers database (as in the style in https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-Credentials).

**My question is:** Given that we're being told we have to incorporate Apple Sign-In into our iOS apps (if we offer general purpose sign-in facilities), how can I do endpoint authentication with my custom server?

I see two alternatives, neither of which I like very much.

First, I can have my client app send an Apple Sign In id_token to my server and ignore the exp (expiry) field. I can regenerate the id_token periodically (apparently, [no more than once a day](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/verifying_a_user)) and send it back to my client. I don't like this idea both because of ignoring the expiry of the token, and because of the need to periodically send the token from server to client. (My app uses multiple sign in systems and this just creates extra difficulty).

Second, [I could have my client send an Apple Sign In refresh token to my server](https://blog.curtisherbert.com/so-theyve-signed-in-with-apple-now-what/). My server would need, of course, to initially generate that refresh token and send it back to the client. I like this idea even less than the first idea. My initial token verification in my custom server would need to access its database to look for a match this token. I can't generally use an Apple endpoint -- because, again, Apple is apparently going to throttle this verification.

Additionally, I don't really like the idea that my custom server can, at best, check on token validity once a day. If the user revokes the app's credentials, I would hope my custom sever would stop being able to operate on behalf of the user relatively quickly.

Thoughts?

---

10/5/19-- update to the first alternative above. Upon actual use of https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/generate_and_validate_tokens for refresh token validation, I find that it is not actually generating an updated id token. It is generating an access token (but Apple doesn't define a use for that), and is validating the refresh token. And so, there is no way to send an updated id token to the client iOS app. Thus, using the first alternative, the expiry date of the id token cannot be used.

10/10/19-- update: I've written a blog article on this subject-- https://medium.com/@crspybits/apple-sign-in-custom-servers-and-an-expiry-conundrum-d1ad63223870

8/6/20-- update: Follow on blog article with possible path forward, pending details from Apple: https://medium.com/@crspybits/part-ii-apple-sign-in-custom-servers-and-an-expiry-conundrum-b3e9735dc079

Comment: Well, I'm going forward with authentication based on the first alternative above. See https://github.com/crspybits/CredentialsAppleSignIn It would be great to get some feedback on this.

Comment: I think apple should provice access token validation interface and remove the limit on refresh token(once a day).

Comment: @ChrisPrince I am now in the same situation. Since you are struggling with this since octobre, did you find some way to achieve this?

Comment: @stamaimer Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately I haven't made further progress. I had some further communication with Apple (see the `Further Update` near the bottom of my [medium article](https://medium.com/better-programming/apple-sign-in-custom-servers-and-an-expiry-conundrum-d1ad63223870)), but the situation has not been resolved.

Comment: If you need to take action on this, it seems like there are several options: 1) Be comfortable with 24 hour intervals between checking authentication with Apple, 2) on your server create some kind of your own OAuth token mechanism to reduce this interval, or 3) use some kind of 3rd party mechanism to add Apple Sign In.

Comment: What I also noticed was that access token is only 3600 seconds valid. Does it mean I have to refresh every hour? And why use Apple token if we are not using any of the Apple's own resources?

Answer (score 3):

In [Get the most out of Sign in with Apple in WWDC 2020](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10173/), at 11:30 in their presentation, they introduce server-to-server notifications to enable your server to monitor user account state changes on a real-time basis.

So far, few details on this though.

----------------- UPDATE (12/23/20) -----------------

I now have these server-to-server notifications working in a testing environment with my server. Some notes:

1. I decided on the endpoint to use, on my server, to allow Apple to send my server these REST endpoint requests.
2. I pasted that into developer.apple.com > Account > Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles > Identifiers > Select your app identifier > Click 'Edit' next to 'Sign In with Apple' > Server to Server Notification Endpoint
3. This endpoint is effectively unauthorized. E.g., it is made by Apple with no OAuth credential access to your server. How this is setup will depend on your server. I had a means to set up a new endpoint/route for my server that was unauthorized.
4. I have the client side and other parts of my server set up to allow creation of accounts using Apple Sign In. So, using one of those accounts, I now started taking actions that would cause Apple to invoke their server-to-server notification endpoint on my server. I wanted to reverse engineer the details of the endpoint request Apple is making, since details are scarce.
   This provides some ideas on how to cause the notification events to occur:
   [How to revoke Sign in with Apple credentials for a specific app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58018184/how-to-revoke-sign-in-with-apple-credentials-for-a-specific-app)
   You can revoke credentials, but it's easier (because you can do it repeatedly) to enable and disable the email relay. Of course, to do this, you have to initially sign-in with Apple using the private/email relay.
5. I next learned two things:

a) After you take the action (e.g., revoke the email relay), the server-to-server notification endpoint is accessed on your server within about 30 seconds. I had added various log output into my server, so could watch my server log and see this happening.

b) The endpoint request Apple makes to your server has body data containing JSON in the following format:
`{"payload" : "-- SNIP -- JWT"}`

I'm using the following Swift structure to decode this.

```
    struct ApplePayload: Decodable {
        let payload: String // JWT
    }
```

6. As Apple has indicated in the WWDC 2020 video (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10173/), the main content of the body data is a JWT. Above, this is the value of the key "payload" in the JSON.
7. The next step is decoding this JWT. I just guessed that it would use the same mechanism for decoding as with the JWT in other parts of the Apple Sign In server-side process. And specifically, in decoding the identity token (a JWT) passed up to your server by a client using Apple sign in. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple
   I had some code that did this JWT decoding, so I factored that out and put it in a common place:
   https://github.com/SyncServerII/AppleJWTDecoder.git
   Integrating that into my server-side processing of Apple's server-to-server notification requests, I found that indeed this JWT can be decoded in this manner.
8. Another aspect that became evident is that the structure indicated by Apple in the WWDC 2020 video isn't 100% what is present in the JWT, after decoding. Specifically, in my tests so far at least the `events` field is not an array, rather it has a single value. See https://github.com/SyncServerII/AppleJWTDecoder/blob/main/Sources/AppleJWTDecoder/AppleSignInClaims.swift for a Swift structure.

I am now successfully parsing the JWT. The next main step on my server is to actually utilize the different event types in my server to take actions. For me this is going to involve the two account (not email) related actions:

> User decided to stop using their Apple Id with your application. And
> should be treated as a sign-out by the user. E.g., when a user decides
> to disconnect your application from Settings. (From
> https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10173/)
>
> Also considered a request from user to "delete their app account"
> (broader context: "Server to Server Notification Endpoint Sign in with
> Apple server to server notifications allow you to receive important
> updates about your users and their accounts. Notifications are sent
> for each app group when users change mail forwarding preferences,
> delete their app account, or permanently delete their Apple ID. Each
> group of apps can have one URL, which must be absolute and include the
> scheme, host, and path. TLS 1.2 or higher is required to receive
> notifications. Learn more.") To see these docs, go to:
> developer.apple.com > Account > Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles >
> Identifiers > Select your app identifier > Click 'Edit' next to 'Sign
> In with Apple' > Server to Server Notification Endpoint

```
case consentRevoked = "consent-revoked"
```

> User has asked Apple to delete their Apple Id. The user identifier will now no longer be valid.

```
case accountDelete = "account-delete"
```

My plan is to take both of these events as equivalent- and delete the user's account on my server. I'm then going to have to consider how to communicate this to my client (iOS app). It will need to know that the user has deleted their account.

Comment: Seems like we can set this up already. I saw an option on the developer dashboard. I didn't test it myself yet, as I'm still trying to wrap my head around all of the Apple Sign In. I've had Facebook and Google logins implemented for a long time, and Apple is messing up the rest of my auth flow. Just curious, do you ever ask the user to re-sign in with Apple (i.e. if you have long-lived tokens or your own refresh token system) or do you solely depend on refreshing apple's `refresh_token` to make sure they're still valid?

Comment: Hey, @Merricat-- thanks! Can you please give a few more details on how to access this option on the developer dashboard? On the other point, this is vapor ware for me at this point-- I don't have my implementation completed. This is partly because of the ongoing issues with Apple Sign In, and partly because I'm (for other reasons) overhauling the system where I plan to have Apple Sign In. I do not plan, however, to ask users to re-sign in. See also the 8/6/20-- update I added above.

Comment: Sure thing, here are the steps: go to developer.apple.com > Account > Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles > Identifiers > Select your app identifier > Click 'Edit' next to 'Sign In with Apple' > Server to Server Notification Endpoint. Thank you so much for the info. I think I'm going to end up relying on apple's `refresh_token` to validate the user every time their `access_token` expires if it's been more than 24h since the last validation. I'm thinking of also asking the user to re-sign in every 5-6 months, but I don't know if it's necessary. Good luck, let me know how it goes!!

Comment: Also, regarding your 8/6/20 post update, I would suggest having the `getCredentialState` call only handle a local logout (ie. delete any keychain access tokens, apple userId, etc). As you said, if server-to-server is implemented, then your server would automatically remove access to that user. Even w/o server-to-server, your next validation of apple's `refresh_token` would fail, so realistically the time window for a breach would be at most 24h.

Comment: Thanks! Good call on `getCredentialState`.

Comment: Just checked out the `developer.apple.com > Account > Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles > Identifiers > Select your app identifier > Click 'Edit' next to 'Sign In with Apple' > Server to Server Notification Endpoint.`. I'm going to add that to my blog post. Thanks! A silent step along the way: I've been unable to find associated docs (except for https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/devde676e696 which doesn't document the server-to-server aspect). A path forward would be to add in an endpoint here and add custom server logging to  reverse engineer the endpoint parameters/HTTP body etc.

Comment: Glad I could help! I don't think there are any docs currently, but the apple video you linked above tells you what data to expect from the their notifications (at 12:14). It's a JWT containing an "events" claim, each event is an associative array with data like `"type": "email-disabled"`, so it should be pretty straightforward from there (decode and validate the JWT, extract event `type` and `sub` claims, deal with them accordingly)