# Sign In With Apple - App Access Token Support?

Tags: swift, web-services, facebook-login, apple-sign-in

I'm just looking at migrating an existing Login with Facebook flow over to Sign in with Apple with the hope of eliminating FB Login entirely from our iOS app.

The client side seems straight forward enough, however there's one topic I can't seem to see any documentation or discussion on Stack Overflow about - a Sign In with Apple equivalent for FB App Access Tokens.

Facebook Login supports different token types (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) and currently our app back end supports 2 authentication flows.

1. From End App Users, they Login with Facebook, send the provided client User Access Token to the app backend which validates the token against Facebook and then issues an app specific JWT token to the app client that is used in further app API calls until expiry.
2. From backend server components. These request an App Access Token from Facebook e.g.

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token  
  ?client_id={your-app-id}  
  &client_secret={your-app-secret}  
  &grant_type=client_credentials"
```

The App Access Token is then send to the app backend which validates the token against Facebook and then issue an app specific JWT token that is used in further server to server API calls until expiry.

Replacing 1 above seems straightforward but what about 2? Is there a mechanism for achieving the same flow  with Sign In with Apple?

It seems like the https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi would be the API to use for validation but is there a way to generate an App Access Token equivalent for Sign In with Apple in the first place to validate using this REST API?

Thanks

Comment: In Sign in with Apple's case you can get an authorization `code` and use this to fetch user information. You can see how it's done in this [tutorial](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/04/what-the-heck-is-sign-in-with-apple).

Comment: Sorry Ayazmon your comment and the associated tutorial do not address the question asked. Having now implemented Sign In with Apple it is not something that is currently supported and appears to be one of several features not available with Sign in with Apple compared to Facebook Login such as an easy way to set-up test user accounts.

Comment: @dead_can_dance did you succeed to do the server side fetching somehow?

Comment: @TomerPeled no App Access Tokens (and Test User Accounts) are not something that seem to be currently supported by Sign In with Apple.

Comment: If I'm getting your point, you are asking if you can use Apple Sign In tokens directly for web services/API. It seems like so far the answer to this is no. See https://medium.com/better-programming/apple-sign-in-custom-servers-and-an-expiry-conundrum-d1ad63223870
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58178187/apple-sign-in-how-to-use-it-for-custom-server-endpoint-authentication

Answer (score 1):

## I think it's possible

I'm not exactly sure how to really use it or validate it yet, but you get an **access_token** in the response from `https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token` when [Generating and Validating Tokens](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/generate_and_validate_tokens)

## Getting an `access_token` from Apple

This example assumes you have an Authorization Grant Code, but the [same is possible](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/generate_and_validate_tokens) if you have a `refresh_token`, etc. instead.

- Prepare a POST request to https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token
- Fill out the following key-values as `x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
client_id
client_secret
code
grant_type
redirect_uri
```

- If successfull, this will return:

```
**access_token**
token_type
expires_in
id_token
```

I'm not sure if this is the type of **access_token** you're looking for, but I wanted to bring it to your attention.

## It may be useless for now

After writing this, I came across [this thread in the forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/121627) where Apple said:

> Currently, the access token only indicates a successful refresh token validation. There are currently no endpoints where it can be used and it is reserved for future use. So, it can be ignored for now.

Comment: lmao was wondering for hours what this access token is here for, thanks !