# Parse Server Sign In with Apple Object saving failed with JWT Expired Error Swift

Tags: swift, parse-server, apple-sign-in

I have implemented the sign in with the apple and connected it to Parse. Everything worked fine until I started saving objects in different classes I got Following Error

> [Error]: jwt expired (Code: 0, Version: 1.17.3) Optional("jwt
>   expired")

Before making any conclusion on this issue I tried to refresh my token by logging In again with apple, I am now able to save objects in any class.

In Facebook there is the **token expiration date**, if token would expire, login In again would do the trick but the problem is there is no expiry date attached with Auth Token returned by Apple.

Is there any other way around to solve this issue or to ask the user every time to signup with apple.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, @salubhayo! By "Auth Token returned from Apple" do you mean the identity token? If so, this is JSON Web Token (JWT) with a relatively short expiry ( a few minutes). Using Apple Sign In tokens to directly do server authentication seems problematic as far as I can tell. E.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58178187/apple-sign-in-how-to-use-it-for-custom-server-endpoint-authentication Happy to be proved wrong, though. IMO, you should argue your case in a bug report to Apple. The more people that talk to them about this, the better chance we have that they'll act.

Comment: @ChrisPrince definitely it's an identity token which I'm using to create Auth Data for **Parse Server** but currently, the apple doesn't provide any mechanism to refresh token either at client end or server-side.

Comment: yep. I fully agree. There appears to be a means to refresh the identity token, server-side, but just once every 24 hours. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/tokenresponse
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/generate_and_validate_tokens
Note that I've not checked the resulting id token to see that it's expiry date is updated. And the once-per-24-hours is too limiting for my case. Further, what I personally need is means to refresh the id token client side.

Comment: @ChrisPrince Enable Revocable Session for the user after **Parse configuration** in **appdelegate** then you won't need to refresh **JWT**

`PFUser.enableRevocableSessionInBackground()`

Comment: This looks like something specific to parse (https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Classes/PFUser.html). I'm not using Parse.