# How can I reset my phone so I can receive scopes from Sign In WithApple

Tags: apple-sign-in

I have read that the scopes [fullname, .email] are returned only the first time with Sign In With Apple.  I tested my app without knowing this.

I'm just in development right now.  How can I reset so the fullname and email are returned again?

Comment: un-related and no-good Question to SwiftUI!, delete or change the Question

Comment: OK. I removed the SwiftUI.

Answer (score 1):

Source:[How to revoke Sign in with Apple credentials for a specific app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58018184/how-to-revoke-sign-in-with-apple-credentials-for-a-specific-app)

You can do this from the iPhone Settings. Open the Settings app then tap on your name at the top. Then press "Password & Security", then "Apple ID logins". They should all be listed there and can be deleted.